# Opencv JNA&C++ FaceRecognizer Causes JVM to crash

Tags: java, c++, opencv, jvm, jna

I have been programming a Java version of the FaceRecognizer library. I can successfully initialize a new FaceRecognizer (with Fisherface as default) in my Java OpenCV project. I used JNA to accomplish this. But recently, I found out that the "train" method has bugs so I decided to do the entire recognition in the DLL file and return a double value at last. But when I made a new FaceRecognizer like this:

```
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = Algorithm::create<FaceRecognizer>("FaceRecognizer.Fisherfaces");
```

or

```
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
```

it does compile and build successfully! But when I use them to train like this:

```
model->train(libList,idList);
```

(libList is vector and idList is vector)

the JVM (through JNA to my Java OpenCV project).

It says :

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x60b2510b, pid=31264, tid=13256

Problematic frame:
C  [opencv_core248.dll+0x510b]
```

I am guessing it is something to do with reference or pointer because even if I run

```
model->name();
```

it also crashes. Seems like it is a problem with "model".
I truly appreciate all of your help! Thank you very much!

This is the logged file:

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0008bc00):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=13256,     stack(0x01070000,0x010c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x010bf098, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x08da0174
ESP=0x010bf08c, EBP=0x010bf0a4, ESI=0x010bf0b0, EDI=0x010bf3e4
EIP=0x60b2510b, EFLAGS=0x00010286

Top of Stack: (sp=0x010bf08c)
0x010bf08c:   bdaf0099 010bf0b0 00000000 010bf3e4
0x010bf09c:   60c941e9 ffffffff 010bf3f0 61e42598
0x010bf0ac:   010bf198 bdac87d8 010bf490 00000000
0x010bf0bc:   00000000 010bf148 010bf148 010bf120
0x010bf0cc:   010bf120 cccccccc 00000000 cccccccc
0x010bf0dc:   cccccccc 42ff0000 00000000 00000000
0x010bf0ec:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x010bf0fc:   00000000 00000000 00000000 010bf0e8 

Instructions: (pc=0x60b2510b)
0x60b250eb:   a1 00 00 00 00 50 51 56 a1 e0 37 d1 60 33 c5 50
0x60b250fb:   8d 45 f4 64 a3 00 00 00 00 c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00
0x60b2510b:   8b 01 8b 75 08 8b 50 0c 56 ff d2 8b c8 e8 e3 f7
0x60b2511b:   ff ff c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00 c7 45 f0 01 00 00 00 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x010bf098 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0008bc00
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x08da0174 is an unknown value
ESP=0x010bf08c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0008bc00
EBP=0x010bf0a4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0008bc00
ESI=0x010bf0b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0008bc00
EDI=0x010bf3e4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0008bc00
```

Comment: What is: `Ptr<FaceRecognizer>`? If it holds a pointer to some allocation and is destroyed when the function returns (like `std::unique_ptr`), that is where your access violation is. Can you show the `entire` log file? Would also be nice to see the JNI code (code passing the data to the java side).

Comment: yes, please show the jni wrapper method.

Comment: I will share it on my blog after I am done with my project but I need help. I found out that the memory address is made but the value of the memory address is NULL. Also, when I ask Algorithm to "getList", it crashes too. Anything calling the pointer or reference would crash making me feel like it is the "createFisherFaceRecognizer()" problem. I think it is with the libraries at I might have missed to import. Your ideas?

Comment: nope, not on your blog. here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed! Yes, it is a problem with the " createFisherFaceRecognizer() " because it is derived from " cv.hpp". It shows up in the IntelliSnse of Visual Studio because it is from class Cv but I didn't import the correct libraries. I added a " d" to the end of each opencv.lib file and I also imported cvcore and cvcorex. Now it works. If you have problems like mine, it is probably such. I will happily share my code once I am done.